# Spawn another output window/terminal from Java

Tags: java, terminal

In my program I have many outputs that help me to debug my program when things go south. However, due to the way that it is programmed, it's hard to get timing values for each iteration due to the mass of other outputs flooding the window.

So I wanted to know whether there was any way to spawn another terminal window and output exclusively the timing outputs there?

Comment: you could use the logging API and configure different loggers for the different kinds of output.

Comment: Since you're asking for terminals, You could use System.out for one set of logging and System.err for another set.